# NSOutlineView Data Source

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nsoutlineview

I've created an NSOutlineView(Sourcelist) in Xcode, given it an outlet, and made my class implement NSOutlineViewDataSource. I then `[outlineview setDataSource:]`, and I see that it creates the cells with the number of items from my array, but they are all blank.

```
sub1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"General Data",@"Most Played", @"Misc",@"Log", nil];
sub2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"General Data", @"Most Played", @"Misc",@"Log", nil];

items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sub1,sub2,nil];

[outlin setDataSource:self];
[outlin reloadData];

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
{        
    return [self outlineView:outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:item] != 0;
}

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item
{    
    if (item)
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            return [item count];
        else
            return 0;
    else
        return [items count];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
{
    if (item) {
        return [item objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    else
        return [items objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)theColumn byItem:(id)item
{
     if (item) {
         if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
             return @"YES"; // Return name for this node
         else
             return item;
     }
     else
         return @"List Root";
}
```

Everything appears to be in order, an it kind of works, except all the text is blank. It creates all the root items and such just without text.

Comment: Have you checked your bindings in Interface Builder for the outline view's cell?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to build a table column for your NSOutlineView like this:

```
NSTableColumn *titleColumn = [[[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"identifier"] autorelease];
[[titleColumn headerCell] setStringValue:@"Header"];
[self addTableColumn:titleColumn];
[self setOutlineTableColumn:titleColumn];
```